# Авторизация на сайте через Steam на Js

Tags: javascript, html, steam

Как можно реализовать регистрацию на сайте через steam? Чтобы в итоге получить логин пользователя

Comment: это делается через `node-js`....

Comment: можете дать пример?

Comment: http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-steam/